# Reinstalling internet explorer on windows 7

Tags: windows-7, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

I have unistalled IE 8 on windows 7. I would like to reinstall IE and see if that fixes it however windows 7 is not listed on microsofts list of operating systems it supports. The 64 bit vista version refuses to install.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IE8 is a part of Windows 7 (a feature).

Try this:

- Close all programs.
- Click Start , and then click Control Panel.
- Under Programs, click Uninstall a program.
- In the tasks pane, click Turn Windows features on or off.
- In the list of windows features, check mark Internet Explorer 8.
- Hit Ok.

HTH

Comment: it didn't fix lotro however I have iE8 back, thank you

Comment: And the answer to why I couldn't login was solved when the new IE took me to the american servers not the european ones :)

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you uninstalled it? Did you just hide it?

Go to Control Panel and search for "Set Program Access and Computer Defaults"

Under "Choose a configuration", click on whichever radio button is selected (mine is "Custom")

Under the "Choose a default web browser" section ensure there is a tick next to "Enable access to this program" next to Internet Explorer